# Client-side routing in an embedded shopify app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, shopify, react-router-dom

I'm trying to enable client-side routing using `react-router` inside an embedded shopify app.
I used [this guidline](https://shopify.dev/apps/tools/app-bridge/getting-started/using-react#using-a-custom-router) from Shopify but I don't clearly understand what should be in a `./Routes` file.
I tried to search for similar questions on Stack overflow or blogs, but information there is a bit outdated.

My code:
App.jsx:

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloProvider,
  HttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
} from "@apollo/client";
import {
  Provider as AppBridgeProvider,
  useAppBridge,
} from "@shopify/app-bridge-react";
import { authenticatedFetch } from "@shopify/app-bridge-utils";
import { Redirect } from "@shopify/app-bridge/actions";
import { AppProvider as PolarisProvider } from "@shopify/polaris";
import translations from "@shopify/polaris/locales/en.json";
import "@shopify/polaris/build/esm/styles.css";

import {useMemo} from 'react';
import {useLocation, useNavigate, BrowserRouter, RouterProvider} from 'react-router-dom';

import { HomePage } from "./components/HomePage";
import Routes from './Routes';

function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useMemo(
    () => ({replace: (path) => navigate(path, {replace: true})}),
    [navigate],
  );
  console.log(new URLSearchParams(document.location.search).get("host"))  
  const router = useMemo(
    () => ({
      location,
      history,
    }),
    [location, history],
  );
  return (
    <PolarisProvider i18n={translations}>
      <AppBridgeProvider
        config={{
          apiKey: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
          host: new URLSearchParams(document.location.search).get("host"),
          forceRedirect: true,
        }}
        router={router}
      >
        <MyProvider>
            <Routes />
        </MyProvider>
      </AppBridgeProvider>
    </PolarisProvider>
  );
}

function MyProvider({ children }) {
  const app = useAppBridge();

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    link: new HttpLink({
      credentials: "include",
      fetch: userLoggedInFetch(app),
    }),
  });

  return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>;
}

export function userLoggedInFetch(app) {
  const fetchFunction = authenticatedFetch(app);

  return async (uri, options) => {
    const response = await fetchFunction(uri, options);

    if (
      response.headers.get("X-Shopify-API-Request-Failure-Reauthorize") === "1"
    ) {
      const authUrlHeader = response.headers.get(
        "X-Shopify-API-Request-Failure-Reauthorize-Url"
      );

      const redirect = Redirect.create(app);
      redirect.dispatch(Redirect.Action.APP, authUrlHeader || `/auth`);
      return null;
    }

    return response;
  };
}

export default function AppWrapper() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

./Routes.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {createBrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import { HomePage } from './components/HomePage';
import { Instructions } from './components/Instructions';

export default function Routes() { 
    const routes = createBrowserRouter([
        {
        path: "/",
        element: <HomePage />,
        },
        {
            path: "/statistics",
            element: <HomePage />,
        },
        {
            path: "/integration",
            element: <Instructions />,
        }
    ]);

    return  routes
}
```

Any help is massively appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the important note from the docs is this:

> If you are using React Router, ensure that the Provider is a child of
> the router component.

Code:

> ```
> export function MyApp() {
>   const config = { apiKey: '12345', host: host };
>   const navigate = useNavigate();
>   const location = useLocation();
>   const history = useMemo(
>     () => ({ replace: (path) => navigate(path, { replace: true })}),
>     [navigate],
>   );
>
>   const router = useMemo(
>     () => ({
>       location,
>       history,
>     }),
>     [location, history],
>   );
>
>   return (
>     <Provider
>       config={config}
>       router={router}
>     >
>       <Routes />
>     </Provider>
>   );
> }
> export default function AppWrapper() {
>   return (
>     <BrowserRouter> // <-- Router wraps App
>       <App />
>     </BrowserRouter>
>   );
> }
> ```

This is because the `App` component necessarily needs a routing context provided to it from higher in the ReactTree so it can use the `useNavigate` and `useLocation` hook and proxy a `history` object to the `navigate` function.

At this point the `Routes` component can be any React component that renders some routes to be matched and rendered. For your case you can't use `createBrowserRouter` and define the router *below* the `App` component that is trying to consume it. Use the older `BrowserRouter` as in the `AppWrapper` example above, and `Routes` is a component that renders the routes you want.

Example

```
import React from 'react';
import { useRoutes } from "react-router-dom";
import { HomePage } from './components/HomePage';
import { Instructions } from './components/Instructions';

export default function Routes() { 
  const routes = useRoutes([
    { path: "/", element: <HomePage /> },
    { path: "/statistics", element: <HomePage /> },
    { path: "/integration", element: <Instructions /> }.
  ]);

  return routes;
}
```

...

```
...
import Routes from './Routes';

function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const history = useMemo(
    () => ({replace: (path) => navigate(path, {replace: true})}),
    [navigate],
  );

  const router = useMemo(
    () => ({
      location,
      history,
    }),
    [location, history],
  );

  return (
    <PolarisProvider i18n={translations}>
      <AppBridgeProvider
        config={{
          apiKey: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
          host: new URLSearchParams(document.location.search).get("host"),
          forceRedirect: true,
        }}
        router={router}
      >
        <MyProvider>
          <Routes />
        </MyProvider>
      </AppBridgeProvider>
    </PolarisProvider>
  );
}
```

### Alternative

If you want to use the new `react-router-dom@6.4` Data APIs then the following refactor might work for you. Create the new data-connected `BrowserRouter` but refactor the routes such that `App` is rendered as a layout route (*i.e. it is rendered on a `Route` and itself renders an `Outlet` for the nested routes to render their content into*).

Example:

App

```
...
import { Outlet, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
...

function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const history = useMemo(
    () => ({replace: (path) => navigate(path, {replace: true})}),
    [navigate],
  );

  const router = useMemo(
    () => ({
      location,
      history,
    }),
    [location, history],
  );

  return (
    <PolarisProvider i18n={translations}>
      <AppBridgeProvider
        config={{
          apiKey: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
          host: new URLSearchParams(document.location.search).get("host"),
          forceRedirect: true,
        }}
        router={router}
      >
        <MyProvider>
          <Outlet />
        </MyProvider>
      </AppBridgeProvider>
    </PolarisProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Create the `Router`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import App from './path/to/App';
import { HomePage } from './components/HomePage';
import { Instructions } from './components/Instructions';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <HomePage />,
      },
      {
        path: "/statistics",
        element: <HomePage />,
      },
      {
        path: "/integration",
        element: <Instructions />,
      }
    ],
  },
]);

export default function Router() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

...

Import and render the router now:

```
import Router from '..path/to/Router';

...

<Router />
```